# Use Entity Framework automatic migrations only on one SQL Server schema

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I've been tasked to create a web API for a vendors database that we host on-site ourselves. What we want to do is create EF data models/db sets for some of the existing vendor tables, but we also want to create a special schema for our custom tables that store the relationships between the vendor data and our other applications.

The thing I've been wondering about is how can we use automatic migrations and database initialization just for our special schema and let the vendor application manage its tables separately on its own. Is this possible?

Comment: I find that Entity Framework Automatic Migrations only work in a small number of cases, particularly those when the entire DB schema is generated entirely from your own code. It doesn't work with Database First, for example, and it's easy to trip it up with renamed columns - I'm not convinced it will save you any time and trouble in this case, and instead will result in more work in trying to force it to work.

Comment: I suggest managing your own schema upgrade scripts yourself - at least that way you get full control, and tools like SSMS and SSDT can automatically generate change-scripts as you make changes in designers.